# Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes

Tags: npm, bower, yarnpkg

I'm migrating from bower to yarn, and in my `bower.json` file I have this dependency:

```
Snap.svg": "snap.svg#^0.4.1
```

When I tried to do the same in the yarn dependencies file, I got this error :

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "snap.svg@^0.4.1": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

First, the npm package name -- which yarn uses since it uses `package.json` -- is `snapsvg` whereas `snap.svg` (with a dot) is only used for Bower. See the [snapsvg npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapsvg). The error you see is in reference to that dot in the package name.

Second, when I test installed it with yarn 1.2.1, I noticed that it complained that 0.4.1 was not available:

```
Couldn't find any versions for "snapsvg" that matches "^0.4.1"
? Please choose a version of "snapsvg" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
> 0.5.1
  0.5.0
  0.4.0
  0.3.0
  0.1.0
```

The resulting `package.json` entry should look like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "snapsvg": "^0.4.0"
}
```

and `yarn.lock`:

```
snapsvg@^0.4.0:
  version "0.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/snapsvg/-/snapsvg-0.4.0.tgz#e0767014167825957de7e125c29b0fa89796ea03"
  dependencies:
    eve "~0.4.2"
```

Generally, when something weird like this happens, use [`yarn add`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) with the package name manually and see what it does.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it by simply using below command

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```