# Simple explanation of EINVALIDTAGNAME?

Tags: javascript, json, npm, error-handling

I am testing out a tutorial for a simple Discord bot that was written with Windows in mind (I am on Mac). I am very inexperienced and keep hitting the below error message when I try to follow one of the final steps which would ideally automatically install files into my folder for my bot directly.

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
>   npm ERR! Invalid tag name "–save": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Comment: Please let us know what you are trying to do and what your code looks like – it's hard to tell what's happening without knowing your code (or whatever the tutorial's steps are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893065/tags-may-not-have-any-characters-that-encodeuricomponent-encodes)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the site you got the tutorial from turned `--save` (with two hyphen-minuses) into `–save` (with an en-dash). If you see anything online telling you to enter fancy dashes into a terminal, it probably got mangled by blogging software. Generally (but not always), if the option you're entering is a word, it should be preceded by `--`, and if the option is a single letter, it should be preceded by `-`.

If you're using a recent version of npm, you can drop the `--save` option completely.